# Assistance with understanding why my React state is not updating

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, react-360

I am creating a react 360 (formerly reactvr) project using MobX. I had such a pain setting up with Redux that I chose to use MobX for simplicity. What I am trying to recreate is the project that is presented in this youtube video [React VR presentation 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJg8CMPNp3w&t=1118s).

I am relatively new to the JS and VR scene and am trying to make sense of react and specifically state management libraries like Redux and Mobx. Now onto the code. Here I have the following in my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { decorate, observable, computed } from "mobx";
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

import {
  asset,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  VrButton,
} from 'react-360';

import Entity from 'Entity';

export default class PlanetMenu extends React.Component {
  planetName = '';

  get selectedPlanetModel() {
    return this.planetName;
  }

  select(planet) {
    this.planetName = planet;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.panel}>

        <View>
          <VrButton
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onClick={() => this.select('earth')}>
            <Text style={styles.planetName}>Earth</Text>
          </VrButton>

          <VrButton
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onClick={() => this.select('saturn')}>
            <Text style={styles.planetName}>Saturn</Text>
          </VrButton>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
};

decorate(PlanetMenu, {
  selectedPlanetModel: computed
})

decorate(PlanetMenu, {
    planetName: observable,
})

export class ModelView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Entity
        style={{transform: [{scaleX: 1.25}, {scaleY: 1.25}]}}
        source={{obj: asset(`${PlanetMenu.selectedPlanetModel}.obj`), mtl: asset(`${PlanetMenu.selectedPlanetModel}.mtl`)}}
      />
    );
  }
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PlanetMenu', () => PlanetMenu);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ModelView', () => ModelView);
```

What I have is basically two buttons that when clicked will dynamically render the selected planets 3D models. It's not working as expected however.

In my `ModelView` class the line that contains `${PlanetMenu.selectedPlanetModel}.obj` is interpolating as `'undefined.obj'`. I'm wondering why this is? The `planetName` variable in `PlanetMenu` is being updated but it doesn't seem to be getting accessed correctly. Can someone help point me in the right direction. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are accessing static property, `PlanetMenu.selectedPlanetModel`. While `selectedPlanetModel` is instance property.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance @estus. I can't help but feel this is not good practice. Am I right in this assumption and if so, where can I read up on best practices aside from the tutorials? Do you have recommendations?

Comment: This is not a bad practice but a mistake. Static and instance methods are different things. You cannot access `selectedPlanetModel` from `PlanetMenu` class, and there's no `PlanetMenu` class instance to work with. I'm not sure what would be the correct solution in your case since I'm not using Mobx but I'd suggest to start with clarifying a misconception about static/instance members and examining how ES6 classes work.